# оптимизация записи в STL вектор

Tags: c++, оптимизация, vector, stl

У меня какая-то странная ситуация, которую никак не могу понять.

Есть такой код:

```
typedef std::vector<figure_info_t> figure_t;
typedef std::vector<figure_t> figures_t;

void
add_result
(figures_t& results, figure_info_t* localResult, const int figuresAmount)
{
    figure_t figuresData;

    for (int index = 0; index < figuresAmount; index++)
    {
        figuresData.push_back(localResult[index]);
    }

    results.push_back(figuresData);
}
```

Тут мне что-то подумалось, что написано как-то по детски неуклюже и переписал вот так:

```
void
add_result
(figures_t& results, figure_info_t* localResult, const int figuresAmount)
{
    results.push_back(figure_t(localResult, localResult + figuresAmount));
}
```

Дешево и сердито

**Вопрос:**

Но почему-то новый код стал работать медленнее, совсем чуть-чуть, но стабильно (общая работа приложения замедлилась на 2%, а ведь в ней вызов `add_result` не является очень уж частым).

**Так вот:** почему могла возникнуть такая ситуация? Вроде же и код короче и используются возможности `std::vector` без лишнего самопала. Так почему же идет замедление?

Comment: Вы же знаете что push_back может резервировать дополнительную память, помимо вставки нового элемента, и что если известно примерно сколько будет элементов, то лучше сначала вызывать метод `reserve(std::size_t n)`, чтобы при `push_back`  не происходило выделение дополнительной памяти ? Это никак не относится к Вашему вопросу, но всё же решил уточнить

Comment: да, конечно знаю
но тут как раз весь смысл в том, что в ручном коде не было ничего такого, а новый код стал короче и т.д., но замедлился, хотя и незначительно, возможно конечно, что компиляторы какие-то уж очень умными стали

Comment: код короче, есстественно еще не значит, что он быстрее

Comment: это понятно, то тут надо предположить, что insert менее эффективен, чем тупой for+push_back, т.е. внутри insert какие-то лишние проверки стоят

Comment: А какой компилятор вы используете? По всем канонам, быстрее должен быть именно второй вариант и, возможно, намного.

Comment: Откуда уверенность в а) замедлении приложения, б) в том, что замедление вызвано этим изменением?

Comment: может проблема в конструкторе figure_t, а не в векторе?

Comment: случайно, замеряете не debug-сборку?

Comment: точно нет, проверял, да иначе и скорость бы на порядки там просела

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика подсказывает:

```
figure_t(localResult, localResult + figuresAmount)
```

это вызов конструктора(напишем его примерное представление)

```
template<typename In>
std::vector<figure_info_t>::vector<figure_info_t>(In first, In last)
{        
    const size_t n = std::distance(first, last);
    // выделяется неинициализированная память под n штук обьектов                 
    // инициализируется значениями [first, last[
}
```

Практически делается то же самое, что и сделано при первом варианте. Вызов встроенного метода
 `push_back` в `n` раз  может  не быть медленне( выделяется память под один обьект `figure_info_t`), чем   поиск памяти  под  `n`  обьектов   `figure_info_t` , особенно если эти обьекты большие. По моему время выполнения зависит и от железа и от компилятора(хотя второй вариант, в основном, должен быть быстрее), но, по любому, разница должна быть незначительная.

P.S. короткий ответ: на разных компьютерах получите разный результат разницы времены выполнения этих вариантов.

Comment: `figure_t` - это обычный вектор структур, содержащих 4 int значения и всё, т.е. копирование 16 байт происходит

Comment: @Zhihar,  я говорил " особенно если эти обьекты большие ",  а не  "потому что эти обьекты большие"...